# Cannot list content from public buckets

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I created a bucket with public visibility but I cannot find the correct syntax for the oci CLI to list the content of this bucket.

Answer (score 1):

See [Managing Objects - Using the Command Line Interface (CLI) - To list objects in a bucket](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Object/Tasks/managingobjects.htm)

`oci os object list --namespace <object_storage_namespace> --bucket-name <bucket_name>`

Comment: Can you elaborate? What session are you referring to? Describe the steps you are using, your environment, actual results and expected results so that someone may be able to help you.

Comment: Just create a public bucket on oci and from any browser try to navigate to the objects on this bucket. I won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The OCI CLI syntax provided by @totalamateurhour is correct.

When making a request to a public bucket, make sure that either no request signature is sent, or, if a signature is sent, it must be valid. The OCI CLI will always send signed requests. Something like curl or wget can be used to send unsigned requests.

You can receive the JSON list of objects using a browser or curl-like tool with a URL like:

https://objectstorage.<region>.oraclecloud.com/n/<namespace>/b/<bucket>/o/

This is shown in the API documentation at:

https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/objectstorage/20160918/Object/ListObjects

Hope this helps!